# High Chart - columnrange Type depending on months

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi every one I am using Highchart of columnrange type, i got chart from 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/ and modified it according to my need , now i need months name in the x-axis and y-axis values are fixed . Currently i am not able to change the x-axis numbers to months.

My script is as :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Employee Bill Pending Detail'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Month Wise'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Bank Bill Pending', 'Clam Pending']
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Session (2013-14)'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },

        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.y ;
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Months',
            data: [
                [1, 4], // Here the [1,4] denotes months between 'Jan' & 'Apr'.
                [2, 8]  // Here the [2,8] denotes months between 'Feb' & 'Aug'.         

            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually really easy. Relevant API documenation:

- [dateFormat()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29)
- [yAxis.type](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.type)

You need to set your data up like this (or use explicit js timestamp):

```
series: [{
    name: 'Months',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1), Date.UTC(2013, 3, 1)], // Here the [1,4] denotes months between 'Jan' & 'Apr'.
        [Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1), Date.UTC(2013, 7, 1)] // Here the [2,8] denotes months between 'Feb' & 'Aug'.         
        ]
}]
```

Note that `Data.UTC()` is zero based so that January is '0'. The last element in that list is the date. Since your data is just by month I made it '1'. You can have whatever you want here as the display on the `dataLabel` and the `tooltip` is handled with the `dateFormat`.

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/axHb8/).

Comment: Dear Sir; Its working but , the Date range at the x-axis is going beyond the selected session months i.e (2013-14). I need to fix the X-Axis label to 12 months example ( Apr'13 to Mar'14). Means my X-Axis nodes are fixed as 12 months of the session.

Comment: It is actually the yAxis - bar charts are rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: @AnandDevSingh, for that you need to set the `min` and `max` values on the yAxis. See this updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/axHb8/1/